# SharePoint Workflow approvals at the folder level?

Tags: workflow, document-library, approval-process

I am new to SharePoint 2013 and am being asked to make a approval process for our Market Reviews.  The reviews are generally 3-7 files of various types (pdf, tbwx, xls etc...).  These are all usually put in a folder and named 'Pheonix Market Review' for example.  I want to have only one approval for the entire folder, but what I am currently getting is an email approval request for EVERY document in the folder.  Is there a way to make it only at the folder level?

I currently have a Document Library with a standard workflow.  Should I use lists or something else?  I want to approve a 'bundle' rather than each individual file.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your files and put them in a document set, and approve the document set all together. You can think of a document as a folder with extra functionality like metadata describing that folder, workflows, etc.

For more information about document sets, please check these links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zp5682BxMWA

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-C49C246D-31F1-4BFE-AFE2-E26698B47E05